# Projectile Motion - Speed Variations has no impact

Tags: projectile-motion

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jGZnMf3rPo
Explain why the bullet would always hit the monkey by solving the
projectile problem.

Despite the initial speed to be of 13m/s or 9m/s, the monkey gets hit.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The monkey and the ball fall at the same rate. Therefore, if you aim at the monkey and drop the monkey as you shoot, they will stay aligned.

Comment: I tried applying acceleration of monkey = -9.81m/$s^2$, and substituting initial velocity 13m/s and 9m/s to get 2 equations but I don't know which element could prove that it will always hit the monkey. I defined time for first shoot was $t_{\text{1}}$ and the time for second shoot is $t_{\text{2}}$ and they are equivalent to the repective $t_{\text{bullet}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the mouth of the cannon is at $(0,0)$ we have the following schematic:

[image]

The height of the monkey above the cannon is $H$ and it's horizontal distance from the cannon is $L$. The initial speed of the ball is $V_0$ at an angle of $\alpha$ degrees.

We can then write the following equations for the monkey's $x$ and $y$ components: 
$$y_m = H - \frac{1}{2}gt^2\tag{1}$$
$$x_m = L$$
And for the ball we have:
$$y_b= (V_0\sin \alpha) t- \frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
$$x_b = (V_0\cos \alpha) t$$
But $\sin \alpha = \frac{H}{\sqrt{H^2+L^2}}$ and $\cos \alpha = \frac{L}{\sqrt{H^2+L^2}}$. Inserting these into the equations for the ball we get:
$$y_b= (V_0\frac{H}{\sqrt{H^2+L^2}}) t- \frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
$$x_b = (V_0\frac{L}{\sqrt{H^2+L^2}}) t$$
Let us see at what time $t_1$ the ball is at the same $x$ coordinate at the monkey by setting $x_b=x_m$, i.e.:
$$ (V_0\frac{L}{\sqrt{H^2+L^2}}) t_1 = L$$
or
$$ t_1 = \frac{\sqrt{H^2+L^2}}{V_0}$$
Inserting $t_1$ into the equation for the $y$ component of the ball, gives the height of the ball at this time:
$$y_b= (V_0\frac{H}{\sqrt{H^2+L^2}}) t_1- \frac{1}{2}gt_1^2$$ or
$$y_b= H- \frac{1}{2}gt_1^2$$
which is exactly the height that the monkey would be at, at that time (see equation 1).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realised that the x component would be equal too, I only assumed that the y components are equal but that's where I had to prove them.